# I can not get data from doInBackground

Tags: android

I have an array of references that I bring into the adapter and load them pictures.

```
public final class Constants {
public static final String[] IMAGES = new String[] {
        "link1",
        "link2",
        "link3",
        "link4",
        "link5",
          ....
}
```

and in MyActivity...

```
...
static  String[] imageUrls = null;
...
imageUrls = Constants.IMAGES;
...
imageLoader.displayImage(**imageUrls[position]**, holder.imageView, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {...}
```

and everything works! but when I try to get links s Internet then there is an error...

```
interface IOnParseResult {void onDone(ArrayList<String> data);}
public class NewThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    Elements title;
    ArrayList<String> data;
    IOnParseResult onParseResult;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {
            Document doc;
            try {
                data = new ArrayList<String>();
                doc = Jsoup.connect(arg[0]).get();
                title = doc.select("div");
                String m;
                for (Element titles : title) {
                    if (titles.children().hasClass("btl")){
                    m = titles.select("img").attr("abs:src");
                    data.add(m);
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
          if (onParseResult == null) return;
          onParseResult.onDone(data);
    }

    public void setOnParseResult(IOnParseResult onParseResult) {
        this.onParseResult = onParseResult;
    }
}
```

and in the output data stream can log in normally, they are loaded, but I can not transfer them to your Activity

```
...
 static  String[] imageUrls = null;
 NewThread t = new NewThread();
...
 t.setOnParseResult(new IOnParseResult() {
             @Override
             public void onDone(ArrayList<String> data) {
                 imageUrls = data.toArray(new String[data.size()]);
             }
         });
         t.execute("http://www.kartinki24.ru/kartinki/3d/");
...
```

error log

```
04-05 10:43:53.973: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1613): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.SimpleFromEclipse/com.example.SimpleFromEclipse.ImageGridActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.SimpleFromEclipse.ImageGridActivity$ImageAdapter.getCount(ImageGridActivity.java:89)
        at android.widget.GridView.setAdapter(GridView.java:131)
        at com.example.SimpleFromEclipse.ImageGridActivity.onCreate(ImageGridActivity.java:70)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
        ... 11 more


// at com.example.SimpleFromEclipse.ImageGridActivity$ImageAdapter.getCount(ImageGridActivity.java:89)
                @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return imageUrls.length;
        }
```

full code

```
public class ImageGridActivity extends AbsListViewBaseActivity {
    static  String[] imageUrls = null;
    DisplayImageOptions options;
    NewThread t;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ac_image_grid);
        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(this));
        t = new NewThread();
        t.setOnParseResult(new IOnParseResult() {
             @Override
             public void onDone(ArrayList<String> data) {
                 imageUrls = data.toArray(new String[data.size()]);
             }
         });
         t.execute("http://www.kartinki24.ru/kartinki/3d/");
        //Log.d("HZ", imageUrls[0]);
        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_stub)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty)
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error)
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisc(true)
            .considerExifParams(true)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            .build();

        listView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        ((GridView) listView).setAdapter(new ImageAdapter());
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                startImagePagerActivity(position);
            }
        });
    }

    private void startImagePagerActivity(int position) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ImagePagerActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.Extra.IMAGES, imageUrls);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.Extra.IMAGE_POSITION, position);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return imageUrls.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder holder;
            View view = convertView;
            if (view == null) {
                view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_grid_image, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                assert view != null;
                holder.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
                holder.progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progress);
                view.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }

            imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrls[position], holder.imageView, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                                         @Override
                                         public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                                             holder.progressBar.setProgress(0);
                                             holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                         }

                                         @Override
                                         public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view,
                                                 FailReason failReason) {
                                             holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                         }

                                         @Override
                                         public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                                             holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                         }
                                     }, new ImageLoadingProgressListener() {
                                         @Override
                                         public void onProgressUpdate(String imageUri, View view, int current,
                                                 int total) {
                                             holder.progressBar.setProgress(Math.round(100.0f * current / total));
                                         }
                                     }
            );

            return view;
        }

        class ViewHolder {
            ImageView imageView;
            ProgressBar progressBar;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From where is the getCount() called exactly? Because if your code is like this

```
t.setOnParseResult(new IOnParseResult() {
             @Override
             public void onDone(ArrayList<String> data) {
                 imageUrls = data.toArray(new String[data.size()]);
             }
         });
t.execute("..");

SomeFunctionThatCausesCallOfGetCount();
```

it will crash. You need it to be

```
t.setOnParseResult(new IOnParseResult() {
             @Override
             public void onDone(ArrayList<String> data) {
                 imageUrls = data.toArray(new String[data.size()]);
                 SomeFunctionThatCausesCallOfGetCount();
             }
         });
t.execute(...);
```

You are probably calling the `setAdapter()` outside the onDone callback. You need to put it inside the callback.

Update:

Change your onCreate like this

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ac_image_grid);
    imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(this));
    t = new NewThread();
    t.setOnParseResult(new IOnParseResult() {
                 @Override
                 public void onDone(ArrayList<String> data) {
                     imageUrls = data.toArray(new String[data.size()]);
                     options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                        .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_stub)
                        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty)
                        .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error)
                        .cacheInMemory(true)
                        .cacheOnDisc(true)
                        .considerExifParams(true)
                        .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                        .build();

                    listView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
                    ((GridView) listView).setAdapter(new ImageAdapter());
                    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                            startImagePagerActivity(position);
                        }
                    });
                 }
             });

    t.execute("http://www.kartinki24.ru/kartinki/3d/");
}
```